# Google docs query when contains value in a range

Tags: google-query-language, google-sheets-query

In google sheets, I want to return a row when a cell in column C contains any value in a range on a different sheet.

The query below does not work. What am I missing?

```
=QUERY(
'Form Responses 1'!$1:$1000,
" select A:G where C contains 'Sheet2'!$A1:$A26"
)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are trying to match a string value in a range on a different sheet:

```
=query('Form Responses 1'!$1:$1000, "SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F,G WHERE A MATCHES '"&JOIN("|",'Sheet2'!$A1:$A26)&"'",1)
```

Hopefully syntax highlighting in the image below makes the above string concatenation operators a little clearer:
[GoogleSheets: Select partial row if target column in data set contains value within range declared in another sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dmFq.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest flagging the rows of interest in `Form Responses 1`, say with in H1:

```
=ArrayFormula(countif(Sheet2!A:A,C1:C))
```

and then selection based on the flags, say with:

```
=QUERY('Form Responses 1'!$1:$1000,"select * where H=1")
```

or if you don't want the flags to appear:

```
=QUERY('Form Responses 1'!$1:$1000,"select A,B,C,D,E,F,G where H=1")
```